# Php/SDK Graph: Send post to wall with picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, image

I use this code:

```
$parameters['link'] = $_POST['link'];
$parameters['picture'] = $_POST['picture'];
$parameters['message'] = $_POST['message'];
$parameters['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$parameters['description'] = $_POST['description'];

$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $parameters);
```

The first times that i tried, i see the image, but now i can't see nothing. I also tried change image name to avoid cache problem, but it doesn't solve the problem.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ID did you get back from `$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $parameters);`?  Use that ID in the graph to search for it.

Comment: When i check my feed https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAN1j2sWq07qrgpfmlSStRm6n2URiWWa5Xl1LozmHJbgMZAxx4FZAQuQXPTsgOUVDosoSsQx7WkvtsFNUVlWINuZAOGxQuHPNQnZBvoka, the element i posted don't have "picture" attribute.

Comment: Try to use the Graph API Explorer and see if you can reproduce it there.

Comment: It works from there. But first times i tried it works from my app too then, without any changes, it just stopped.

Comment: Since you can get it to work in the Graph API explorer and not PHP SDK try doing the same thing via the Javascript SDK to determine if it is a coding issue on your side, or a PHP SDK issue.

Comment: I've uploaded images on another server and it works now. Maybe an Heroku limitation?